# Parsing a string and then storing it an array and parsing it again on shell script

Tags: string, bash, shell, split, string-parsing

I am new to shell scripting and wanted help with splitting a string for example

```
STR="Hello this is stackoverflow Hello I am asking about stackoverflow"
```

So basically I want to split the string whenever there is a word "stackoverflow"
such as

```
Line 1: Hello this is stackoverflow
Line 2: Hello I am asking about stackoverflow
```

Basically I want to split a string here ? Can someone please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use sed to replace stackoverflow and one space with stackoverflow and a linebreak:

```
echo "$STR" | sed -e "s/stackoverflow /stackoverflow\n/"
```